# How to draw Normalize Stack chart using C3 chart?

Tags: c3.js

I want to draw normalize chart using C3 Chart library.

my current code is

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#column-chart-main',
        size: {
            height: $('.chart-area').height()
        },
        data: {
            rows: 
                chartFinalData
            ,
            type: 'bar',
            labels: {
                format: d3.format('%')
            },
            colors: chartFinalColors,
            transition: {
                duration: 100
            }
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true
        },
        axis: {
            y: {
                show: false,
                max: 1,
                min: 0,
                padding: {bottom:0}
            },
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                categories: chartFinalBrands
            },
            rotated: setChartType
        },
        tooltip: {
            format: {
                value:d3.format('%')
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: $scope.chartTrans.showHideLegends,
            position: 'inset',
            inset: {
                anchor: legendPosition,
                x: 10,
                y: 10,
                step: legendSteps,
            }
        }
    });
```

Above code generate simple bar stack chart.
but i need normalize bar stack chart

my current chart is - [current-chart](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html)
i need chart as per - [required-chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3886394/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a normalised stack bar chart then you need to normalise the data first, c3 doesn't have a chart setting itself to work that out

e.g.

```
var data = [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 200, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 100, 200, 150, 50],
            ['data3', 230, 200, 200, 300, 250, 250]
        ]
 ;

  // Normalise
 var scount = data.length;
 for (var n = 1; n < data[0].length; n++) {
  var total = 0;
    for (var m = 0; m < scount; m++) {
        total += data[m][n];
  }
  var ratio = 1.0 / total;
  for (var m = 0; m < scount; m++) {
        data[m][n] *= ratio;
  }
 }

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: data,
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
        ]
    },
    tooltip: {
            format: {
                value:d3.format('%')
            }
        },
    axis : {
        y : {
                //max: 0.95, // for some reason this shows the last tick y as 100%, while 1.0 makes the last y tick 110%, don't know why
                 // thanks to a.n.onymous who figured out this worked better
                max: 1,
                padding: 0,

            tick: {
                format: d3.format("%")
            }
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/697p6hw5/6/